# Removing records from one table based on lack of presence in another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that contain member data - '`members`' and '`member_data`'.  For some reason (I've inherited this) the `member_data` table has more records than the `members` table.  Both tables have a `member_id` column that seems to match up a users info between the two tables.

I would like to remove records from the '`member_data`' table if there is no matching `member_id` found in the '`members`' table.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a `NOT IN` statement :

```
DELETE FROM `member_data`
WHERE `member_data`.`member_id`
NOT IN (
   SELECT `members`.`member_id`
   FROM `members`
);
```

Anyway, you should correct the bug that inserts or not deletes the unexpected rows.

Comment: worked like a champ, thanks! And yes, the no delete bug needs to die a crushing death. :)

Comment: You can use a `NOT IN `statement when administrating your database this way, but `IN` and `NOT IN` uses a lot of resources so you should avoid them inside an application. Glad if I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from member_data where member_id not in (select member_id from members);
```

This query will delete all the records from member_data table not present in members table.